# Is There a maximal space that is a P-space?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology

we guess there is no maximal space which is also a P-space. Am I right? Do u know a counter example?
clarifications:
Maximal space is that space with topology $\tau$ which is maximal crowded topology on X.
crowded: a topology with no isolated point = dense in itself.
P-space:every $G_\delta$ set is open = every prime ideal is a Z-ideal = every prime ideal is a maximal ideal. (for others ref 4M of Gillman , Jerison)

Comment: I don't know what is with all the downvotes to this question. A maximal space which is also a $P$-space will probably be an interesting counterexample.

Comment: If you want to make a linebreak, you can use two spaces at the end of the line or `<br/>`, see [markdown help](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/editing-help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a space $(X,\tau)$, the collection of all $G_\delta$-subsets of $X$ form a base for a stronger topology $\tau_\omega$ on $X$. It is easy to see that $(X,\tau_\omega)$ is a $P$-space (sometimes called the $G_\delta$ modification of $X$). If the original space $(X, \tau)$ is maximal, then there are two possibilities:

1) $(X, \tau_\omega)$ has isolated points. This will happen if and only if the original space has a point of countable pseudocharacter (i.e. a point which is a $G_\delta$).

2) $(X, \tau_\omega)$ is crowded. Then by maximality $\tau_\omega= \tau$ and therefore the original space is already a $P$-space.

It is known that if there are no measurable cardinals then every maximal space has countable pseudocharacter, so it cannot be a $P$-space.

I think it is still open whether there can be a [homogeneous] maximal space with uncountable pseudocharacter (see Question 168 [169] in *Open Problems in Topology II*). Note that by the remarks above, a maximal space in which every point has uncountable pseudocharacter must be a $P$-space.

Comment: Dear Ramiro de la Vega. Can u address where the statement "if there are no measurable cardinals then every maximal space has countable pseudocharacter" mentioned.

Comment: In defining a P-space, Always we suppose the space X is tychonoff at first. If we edit question as follows:        **Is There a maximal tychonoff space that is a P-space?** your answer dosen't work. because $(X,\tau_{\omega})$ need not be a tychonoff space.

Comment: @Vahideh: You can find the statement in the paragraph right before Question 168 in the reference I gave: If a maximal space has a point of uncountable pseudocharacter, then that pseudocharacter and the cardinality of the space are both a measurable cardinal.

Comment: @Vahideh: Hewitt showed that a maximal Tychonoff space is extremally disconnected. Isbell showed that an extremally disconnected $P$-space of nonmeasurable cardinality is discrete. So the situation is pretty much the same for maximal Tychonoff spaces.